# Java getting current date without creating a new Date object

Tags: java

I have a game that loops. I need to check the current number of milliseconds. I don't want to create a new Date object just to get the number of milliseconds that has passed. Is there a way to get the current time without creating a new Date object every iteration of my game loop?

Example:

```
Date d = new Date();

while(true)
{
    long currentTime = d.getCurrentTime();
}
```

In the above code, the value of the currentTime variable would continuously change.

Comment: did you consider  Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();

Comment: @DwB Instantiating Calendars is catastrophically expensive.

Comment: You could also have a look at [`Stopwatch`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html) from the Guava library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than using Date, you can access the static method

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
```

This returns the current time of the given system in milliseconds.